# Switching Between View Controllers Using Variables

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller

I've set-up multiple view controllers on of which is a game over scene. Now I'm able to switch between the scenes with buttons and then linking them afterwards by dragging them into each other. But how do I switch view controllers using variables. For example, I have an integer named lives and when it reaches zero, I want it to switch to the game over view controller.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a much better way more suited to your needs than monitoring the variable. For example when your variable changes to 0 some code must be changing it to 0 mustn't it? And that code that changes it to 0 could post a notification that its changed to 0, to give just one example.

But what you ask *is* possible if you set up Key Value Observing on the variable and then when it changes to the desired value trigger the new view controller.

Look up tutorials on KVO if this is a route you'd like to choose.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply make the variable trigger an event. Something else must trigger the game over event and you can check for the number of lives at that point. For instance, when the player loses a life, check to see how many lives he/she has. If the lives reach 0, then go to the game over view controller by creating a condition that must be met and then either pop or push to your view controller:

```
int lives = 10;

// Game is played and player dies

if (lives == 0) {
    GameOverViewController *gameOverInStack = (GameOverViewController *)[self viewControllerInStackWithClass:[GameOverViewController class]];
    if (gameOverInStack) {
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:gameOverInStack animated:YES];
    } else {
        GameOverViewController *gameOverInstantiated = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StoryboardTitleForViewController"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:gameOverInstantiated animated:YES];
    }
} else {
    // Continue playing game or other desired event
}

- (UIViewController *) viewControllerInStackWithClass:(Class)class {
    for (UIViewController *viewController in self.navigationController.viewControllers) {
        if ([viewController isKindOfClass:class]) {
            return viewController;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: "You cannot simply make the variable trigger an event." That's not correct, KVO would do it.

Comment: I guess it really depends on how you interpret the question. I am aware of KVO but that would be the same as placing an event trigger inside a setVariable method. The variable is still not triggering the event; it is facilitating the trigger. Though your approach is interesting nonetheless.

Comment: I guess its open to interpretation as you say.